# Why are only certain SVG visable with react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

So I am using .svg as icons for my app, and they're hosted online. Some work and others are simply not visible. This is the code I am using.

```
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";
import GlobalStyles from "../styles/GlobalStyles";


const DrawIcon = ({ set_code }) => {

  const onError = (e) => console.log(e); 

  return (
   <SvgUri
      style={GlobalStyles.setIcon}
      uri={set_code } 
      onError={onError}
    />
  );
};

export default DrawIcon;
```

What I have noticed is that SVGs with `viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"` are the ones that aren't visible, while SVGs with `viewBox="0 0 964 432"` and lower are visible on the screen. The files are provided by a third party API, so I'm wondering how to make all files viewable.

Here is:
[an example of a file that works](https://svgs.scryfall.io/sets/m21.svg)
and
[an example of a file that does not work](https://svgs.scryfall.io/sets/akh.svg)

Comment: the file that does not work also has no fill defined. It shouldn't be necessary to have a fill defined but it might be worth adding one to see if that fixes things for you.

Comment: Yes! That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) for the solution. Yes, the files were indeed missing their fill data. Changing the code to:

```
 <SvgUri
      style={GlobalStyles.setIcon}
      uri={set_code } 
      fill={'#000'}
      onError={onError}
    />
```

fixed the problem.